# Loading CSV into MySQL Is This a Bug? - File Not Found Exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I am attempting to load a CSV file into a MySQL database in C# and I keep getting an exception could not read from the result set.  I got the syntax cleaned up in MySQL workbench to the point that I can load a CSV file into the database in MySQL workbenc with no errors.  Trying it in my program, I still get the exception.   The file I am working with has this path and filename:

```
D:\SANCentral\Customer Files\ibm\70738\0918\switch port.csv
```

The exception I get is a 'could not read from resultset'.  Looking at the inner exception I get file not found with this.  I have no idea where that is coming from.  D:\Projects\CSVParser is the location for my project.  I am assuming the MySQL.Data.Client class is doing something with the location I give it to open a file.  This is the path that  the SQL command is trying to load the file from apparently:

```
 {"Could not find file  'D:\\Projects\\CSVParser\\CSVParser\\bin\\Debug\\SANCentralCustomer Filesibm70738'
.":"D:\\Projects\\CSVParser\\CSVParser\\bin\\Debug\\SANCentralCustomer Filesibm70738"}
```

How can I fix this?  I checked the path on the file I want to parse in the debugger and it is correct. I tried moving the .CSV file into the project directory where I am running the project from and I still get an exception, but it is illegal characters in path, instead of file not found.

Here's the C# code to do the load, and the MySQL statement:

```
string ConnectionString =  String.Format(@"server=localhost;userid={0};
        password={1};database=PerformanceMonitors;
Allow User Variables=True", user,password);
        MySqlConnection sqlconnect = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        sqlconnect.Open();
```

Here's the MySQL statement and exccuting the query.  Sorry the string is kinda long:

```
string working = String.Format(@"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{0}' IGNORE
INTO TABLE {1} COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES (`Switch`,`Port`,`WWPN`,@the_slot,`Port Index`,@the_time,
`Interval`,`Port Send Packet Rate`,  
`Port Receive Packet Rate`,`Total Port Packet Rate`,`Port Send Data Rate`, 
`Port Receive Data Rate`,`Total Port Data Rate`, 
Peak Send Data Rate`,`Port Peak Receive Data Rate`,
```

`Port Send Packet Size`,`Port Receive Packet Size`,`Overall Port Packet Size`,
 `Error Frame Rate`,`Dumped Frame Rate`,
 `Link Failure Rate`,`Loss of Sync Rate`,`Loss of Signal Rate`,`CRC Error Rate`,
   `Short Frame Rate`,`Long Frame Rate`,`Encoding Disparity Error Rate`,
  `Discarded Class3 Frame Rate`,`F-BSY Frame Rate`,`F-RJT Frame Rate`,
   `Port Send Bandwidth Percentage`,`Port Receive Bandwidth Percentage`, 
   `Overall Port Bandwidth Percentage`,`Primitive Sequence Protocol Error Rate`,
   `Invalid Transmission Word Rate`,`Link Reset Transmitted Rate`,`Link Reset Received Rate`)

```
    SET Slot = nullif(@the_slot,''), Time= str_to_date(@the_time,'%m/%d/%y %h:%i %p')", files.FirstOrDefault().ToString(), "by_switch");


       string commandreplaced= working.Replace("\n", "");

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandreplaced,sqlconnect);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Oh I can load the file into a datatable using OLEDB, so I know the file path is ok.  I think it is an issue with MySQL.Data libraries, I just have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I finally figured out the answer.   the LOAD DATA FILE statement requires the filename be a string value, it cannot be parameterized.  Unfortunately the MySQLCommand class doesn't like the escaped \ in the file path of a C# string object so it can't find the file.  I got it to work by escaping the escapes thusly:

```
//build the LOAD DATA File command
string working = String.Format("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{0}' IGNORE ", files.FirstOrDefault().ToString()) +
                         String.Format("INTO TABLE {0} COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'", "by_switch")+
                         String.Format(" IGNORE 1 LINES (`Switch`,`Port`,`WWPN`,@the_slot,`Port Index`,@the_time,`Interval`,`Port Send Packet Rate`,")+
                         String.Format("`Port Receive Packet Rate`,`Total Port Packet Rate`,`Port Send Data Rate`,")+        
                         String.Format("`Port Receive Data Rate`,`Total Port Data Rate`,`Port Peak Send Data Rate`,`Port Peak Receive Data Rate`,")+ 
                         String.Format("`Port Send Packet Size`,`Port Receive Packet Size`,`Overall Port Packet Size`,`Error Frame Rate`,")+
                         String.Format("`Dumped Frame Rate`,`Link Failure Rate`,`Loss of Sync Rate`,`Loss of Signal Rate`,`CRC Error Rate`,")+
                         String.Format(" `Short Frame Rate`,`Long Frame Rate`,`Encoding Disparity Error Rate`,")+         
                         String.Format("`Discarded Class3 Frame Rate`,`F-BSY Frame Rate`,`F-RJT Frame Rate`, `Port Send Bandwidth Percentage`,")+
                         String.Format("`Port Receive Bandwidth Percentage`, `Overall Port Bandwidth Percentage`,`Primitive Sequence Protocol Error Rate`,")+
                         String.Format("`Invalid Transmission Word Rate`,`Link Reset Transmitted Rate`,`Link Reset Received Rate`)")+ 
                          String.Format("SET Slot = nullif(@the_slot,''),")+ 
                          String.Format(@"Time= str_to_date(@the_time,'%m/%d/%y %h:%i %p')");


// now escape the escape character
       commandreplaced = commandreplaced.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

   // now execute the command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandreplaced,sqlconnect);
```